# Pass parameters to aggregation primitives in featuretools

Tags: python, featuretools, feature-engineering

I'm using `featuretools` `dfs` function to generate my feature_matrix using time-related aggregation primitives such as `TimeSince` (https://docs.featuretools.com/api_reference.html#deep-feature-synthesis)

```
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                     target_entity="users",
                                     max_depth=2,
                                     agg_primitives=["sum", "max", "min", 
                                                     "mean", "median", "count", 
                                                     "avg_time_between"],
                                     trans_primitives=["day", "year", "month", "weekday", 
                                                       "time_since_previous", "time_since",
                                                      ],
                                     cutoff_time=cutoff_times,
                                     cutoff_time_in_index=True)
```

How do I pass the [unit]  params to the `trans_primitives` argument to change the time unit to minutes, hours, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass parameters to an aggregation or transform primitive, you can create an instance of the primitive with the parameters. This is how to pass the `unit` parameter to the `TimeSince` primitive.

```py
from featuretools.primitives import TimeSince

ft.dfs(
    ...
    trans_primitives=[TimeSince(unit='hours')]
)
```